# Component class instance initialization error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Sometimes we get this error:

> Component class instance initialization error [Definition does not exist on 
>       the client for descriptor:markup://ltng:require]

And sometimes it will only pop up for some users and not others. It doesn't happen all the time and the error doesn't really make sense since that is Salesforces component. I have also seen the same error but with a different standard salesforce component and it seemed to just go away by itself. Im kind of assuming that this has to do with how the page is being loaded by the browser?

I wish I had a better description of how to reproduce this error but all I have is that we have a lightning component which is using the `ltng:require` component to load in Lodash. This lightning component is on a tab which is navigated to by a URL Detail Page Button on a page layout. If the error does pop up it does it upon initialization of the lightning component.

Comment: I realize it's tough with intermittent errors, but if you can come up with an MVR it will greatly improve this question.

Comment: what is a MVR?  Sorry if its obvious

Comment: **M**inimum **V**iable **R**eproduction.